# How to include root resource values in XACML Response when using Multiple decision Hierarchical resource profile?

Tags: authorization, access-control, xacml, xacml3

I am working with XACML 3.0. When I am using the [XACML v3.0 Hierarchical Resource Profile](http://docs.oasis-open.org/xacml/3.0/xacml-3.0-hierarchical-v1-spec-en.html), how can I include root resource values in the XACML Response?

Ex:

```
Customer
    |-->Name
          |-->FirstName,LastName
```

Here,**Customer** is the Top root Resource .**FirstName** and **LastName** are the children of **Name**.

Here in my XACML Request I will send the top resource name **Customer**.By using Hierarchical resource feature of XACML3.0 ,Resource finder will evaluate the child resources.

How can i get root values **Customer** and **Name**  in XACML Response?
Here the XACML Request,

```
<Request xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" CombinedDecision="false" ReturnPolicyIdList="true">
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">read</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">write</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">update</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">delete</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject:subject-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">admin</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
<Attributes Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource">
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">customer</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:root-resource-id" IncludeInResult="true">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">customer</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
<Attribute AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:2.0:resource:scope" IncludeInResult="false">
<AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">Descendants</AttributeValue>
</Attribute>
</Attributes>
</Request>
```

As one can see from the request, it contains 4 action categories, 1 subject category and 1 resource category. The latter uses the hierarchical resource profile. The repetition of the action category follows the Multiple Decision Profile of XACML. Essentially, it means that I am asking: "Can admin update...? Can admin read...? Can admin write...? Can admin delete...?"

Comment: Can you send  your sample XACML request? What does your policy look like? You could use advice and obligations to return the information you need. Also, why would you return customer and name? Surely your PEP already knows this information.

Comment: Did you manage to solve your problem? If so, please share

Comment: Hi,i am so sorry for the late reply.Now i posted XACML Request ,please  check it.

Comment: Is it fair to assume your content would look like <customers>
   <customer>
      <name>
         <lastname>Doe</lastname>
         <firstname>John</firstname>
      </name>
   </customer>
</customers>